# How to add nested objects to DataGrid C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, ienumerable

I have a set of classes that look like the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public Bar bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string id{ get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> foo{ get; set; }
}
```

After deserializing JSON the itemsource of the datagrid is mapped to the ienumerable

```
var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(result);

myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myList;
```

However the problem I am having is that in the grid there are only 3 columns displayed which are the id of Foo, the name of Foo and the bar class. Rather than display the bar class I want to show the id of bar and the name of bar for a total of 4 columns but cannot figure out how to do this.

My xaml code looks like the following:

```
<DataGrid CanUserSortColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="myDataGrid"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind the nested object, you should define the `DataGridTextColumn` (or other column type based on your requirement). Currently the columns are displayed for having `AutoGenerateColumns` property set to true (default value). You can update the XAML to define the data grid columns and do the binding with nested object.

```
<DataGrid CanUserSortColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id }" Header="Id" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding name}" Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding bar.id}" Header="BarId" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding bar.name}" Header="BarName" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without touching **XAML**, in code behind you can use  [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/), like:

```
            var myList = new Wrapper(); 
            var itemSource = myList.foo.Select(x => new {
                Id = x.id,
                Name = x.name,
                BarId = x.bar.id,
                BarName = x.bar.name
            }).ToList();
            myDataGrid.ItemsSource = itemSource;
```